# Jquery Parsing the JSON array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON array like below.

```
[  
   {  
      "0":1,
      "companyID":1,
      "1":"A",
      "companyName":"A",
      "2":"asd",
      "companyAddress":"asd",
      "3":"sad",
      "companyWebAddress":"sad",
      "4":"(222) 222-222",
      "companyPhone":"(222) 222-222",
      "5":"(222) 222-222",
      "companyFax":"(222) 222-222",
      "6":"1",
      "yearOfEstablishment":"1",
      "7":"1",
      "fieldOfBusiness":"1",
      "8":"Job Shop",
      "typeOfProductionService":"Job Shop",
      "9":"Apparel",
      "mainProductsServices":"Apparel"
   }
]
```

I got it from a PHP page by using JQuery + Ajax. I want to parse it and put its values to several textboxes depenging on a selectbox's on change function. Here is what i tried but it is not working.
Any help would be appriciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#companyFillSelectBox").change(function(){
        var value = $("select#companyFillSelectBox option:selected").val();
        //alert();
        //$('#companyNameText').val("SHIT");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'companyFill.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data:{companyID:value},
            success:function(answer){
                $('#companyNameText').val(answer.companyName);
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("An error has occured !");
            }         
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: you probably don't need the index keys as well as named keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an array, so `answer[0].companyName` gets you the first object in the array, and then the `companyName` property.